# Redirecting to details page, i loose all my layout (css, images)

Tags: node.js, express

So i am working with node, express and mongodb and i am building something like a forum. so when a user creates a topic is saves to the db and redirects upon completion to the details page of a topic (based on the id of the created topic). so the url of a topic detail page would be localhost:3000/topicdetail/id

Now my problem is that when i create my routing for the details page it successfully finds one topic based on the id and renders the topic details page but i don't have any layout, so i have no css and images. Anyone has an idea why this is happening

code for my routing of topic details page is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Topic = require('../models/topic');
var db = require('../config/database');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// shows the view of one unique topic based on id
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {

   var topicId = req.params.id;
   console.log('Logging topic id: ' + topicId);

   // find one single topic based on id
   Topic.findById(topicId, function(err, topic)
   {
      if(err){
         return next(err)
         console.log('There was no topic with this ID');
   }
      else
   {
        console.log('Whoop whoop we found a topic matching the requested ID');
        //show the data on the page
        res.render('topicdetail');
   }
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Post your template `topicdetail` please. And you can still see your HTML layout just without css? And maybe the dev console output

Comment: is quit big so i pasted it into pastebin -> http://pastebin.com/yq9vr9UG (content is for now static not yet from the db)

Comment: And what's the output of your developer console in the browser?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (internal server error)

Comment: And what file failed to load?

Comment: as you can see in the screenshot the id is not in the path (http://gyazo.com/04693c7d40b86c5fb540afe31f86d83a)

Comment: all my css, images, js

Comment: please take a screenshot of your console.

Comment: screenshot of console -> http://gyazo.com/d6b5427a2305e7503868e475584c54a7

Comment: Are your templates all in the same folder?

Comment: yes in the folder views -> http://gyazo.com/ee293365a0dd89c427bfe098d86abc56

Comment: and in which folder is your css etc.?

Comment: public > stylesheets > css > style.css and bootstrap.min.css (http://gyazo.com/23a3a42b7ba82376bb3fa96cfdb5ef2d)

Answer (score 2):

Did you tell Express where to find your static files? Something like this:

```
// serve static files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Is the problem specific to the details page? Do you have other pages that are unaffected? All the url in the 500 messages are missing the 'public' part of the path.